# how to create a table named "realizations" with another file name? (FoxPro)

Tags: sql, database, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have to create a table with name "Realizations" but it's file must be named like today's date (example "12092016.dbf"). I can get current date from my C# program but how to set the file name in query string???

My data engine is Visual FoxPro.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are saying you want to create a table with name "Realizations" and then you are saying it must be named like today's date. How would a file's name be both "realizations" and also today's date as a string at the same time? Second, what it has to do with a query? What is that you are really trying to do and cannot?

Comment: @CetinBasoz thx for comment. I need differed name of table and file of this table. Now it's clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? (I assume you mean C# code):

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\My Data Folder"))
{
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"select * from Realizations 
      into table (?)",connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Please note that, naming a table like this is not very safe and also a date string in the format ddMMyyyy is not very safe. Maybe you would want to name it like Realizations_20160913. If so then you could say:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", "Realizations_" +
    DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: Thx for your solution. I'll try if it what i want. I've just corrected my topic description. Anyway thx for note!

Comment: @иванганенко if you appreciate Cetin's answer, you should uptick him.  Click the little arrow on top of the 0.  If it is correct, you should also click the check mark below the zero.

Comment: @Missy thx, i'll, but i don't have enough point to uptick his answer.